# Retrieving sentences for an action performed over an object

Tags: object, action, facebook-opengraph

I need to display the list of all available custom story types for a given App.
I'm retrieving the Apps, custom objects and custom actions with the following call: act_AccountID/connectionobjects?access_token=*_*

```
{
  "id": "6350929420",
  "name": "SMP",  
  "url": "https://apps.facebook.com/smplatform/",
  "type": 2,
  "og_namespace": "smplatform",
  "og_actions": [
    {
      "name": "apps.uses",
      "display_name": "Use",
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "start_time",
          "type": "date_time"
        },
        {
          "name": "end_time",
          "type": "date_time"
        },
        ...
        {
          "name": "place",
          "type": "place"
        }
      ],
      "connected_objects": [
        "website"
      ]
    },      
    {
      "name": "smplatform:cook",
      "display_name": "Cook",
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "start_time",
          "type": "date_time"
        },
        ...
        {
          "name": "explicitly_shared",
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      ],
      "connected_objects": [
        "recipe"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "og_objects": [
    {
      "name": "website",
      "display_name": "Link",
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "url",
          "type": "url"
        },
        ...
        {
          "name": "see_also",
          "type": "url"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "recipe",
      "display_name": "challenge",
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "type",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "determiner",
          "type": "enum"
        }
        ...
      ]
    }
  ],
  "supported_platforms": [
    1,
    2
  ],
  "tabs": [
  ],
  "picture": "https://__"
},
...
```

(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/connectionobjects/)

Now, I want to retrieve the sentences "Use a Link" and "Cook a challenge".
I know that those sentences can be customized in the App Open Graph settings, thus I can't just build the sentence myself.

Is there a way to retrieve those sentences?

Thanks.